# Jobs Candidates Search "profile is no longer visible" Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed a bug in candidate search.

When you click on any profiles in the search results after page 2, it would jump back to the search result list, instead of showing the CV of the candidates. It also produces the following error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! I'll fix this right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! This should be fixed now.

The bug happened because I am a terrible programmer: I'd renamed a variable but I hadn't caught all the usages of it. As a result, the CV view page was downloading only the first page of search results, so it thought any profiles from page 2 onwards were missing.

Comment: Thanks! Another minor related issue (not worth asking a new question): After viewing some profile on page>=2, when I click "back to search results", it always goes back to page 1 instead of the previous page where I clicked the profile.

Comment: OK, thanks for reporting. I'll fix it

Comment: the "back to search results" to page 1 still persists.

Comment: @Titanic Yep, I haven't forgotten about it! Sorry it's taken so long. Legacy code...

Comment: @Titanic Apologies for the delay in fixing this. It should be sorted now